# How to find adjective form of a noun or noun form of an adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

How to tell the noun form of an adjective or adjective form of a noun?

For example, adjective form of the noun "curiosity" is "curious".

Comment: To look up in a dictionary and remember, if you mean how to find. Do you have a particular noun/adjective that you can't find? If you mean suffixes, there are lots of other online resources to be searched before asking here -  for example, [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix).

Comment: @Rompey: Thank you! I just didn't know how to find. Like I wanted to know what is adjective of "decisiveness", which is "decisive".

Comment: That's pretty complicated, @GforOevOerD. There are hundreds of different suffixes that convert one word form to another https://www.learnthat.org/pages/view/suffix.html. Sometimes you have to add a suffix to convert a noun to an adjective wonder->wonderful, sometimes you have to remove a suffix decisiveness->decisive and sometimes you have to remove one suffix and add another. enjoyment-> enjoyable

Comment: JavaLatte puts it very well.  Not only does it depend on the particular word, but it sometimes depends on the *meaning* of the word too.  For example, *race/racial*, but only when *race* means "ethnicity", not when it means "a contest".

Comment: @GforoevOerd:  the -ness suffix is appended to the adjective. swift, swiftness.  Sometimes you need to convert a -y- to an -i-:  speedy, speediness.  happy, happiness.

Answer (score -1):

Acutally, the wordhippo website does it quite well:
https://www.wordhippo.com/

For example, when we search for [an adjective for the noun ***flower***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-adjective-for/flower.html), the website returns six adjectives:

- **flowery** (pertaining to flowers, or decorated with or abundant in flowers)
- **flowered** (a plant that has produced flowers, or something that is covered with flowers)
- **flowering** (a plant that is in bloom)
- **flowerful** (a poetic term meaning flowery or abundant in flowers)
- **flowerlike** (resembling a flower, especially in shape
- **flowerless** (without flowers)